# Power Query – File names loaded from folder become column names, causing failure if new files are later loaded

Tags: powerquery

Power Query sourcing multiple Excel files from a folder.

Files are monthly transactions. The month and year are part of the file names.  When the next month comes, new files (in the same format of course, but with new file names) replace the previous ones in the source folder. Having the new file names causes the query to fail on refresh in the following way.

When the files are combined and displayed to begin the transformations, the files names constitute a column of data (named Source).  One of my steps in transforming the data is to “use first row as headers”; at this point the first file name in that Source column becomes its column header name.
The problem is that when files having new names replace the previous ones, that column name is no longer found, since the row promoted to be the column header is the name of a new file. PQ is looking for a column header having the original file name and doesn’t find it, so subsequent transformations using that column cause errors.

The error message is: “[Expression.Error] The column ‘[OriginalFileName]’ of the table wasn’t found.”

Basically, that original file name takes on a permanent role as a column name that is part of the query.

I successfully managed to get around the problem by manually renaming all the columns instead of promoting the first data row to be the column headers.  Now files with new names are processed without complaint. But this solution is clunky and I would like to keep the step of promoting the first row to be the header.

Does anyone know how to overcome this problem?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerQuery - Folder Query import new files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636226/powerquery-folder-query-import-new-files)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Before posting a question here, please do a little research. This question is a duplicate of the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636226/powerquery-folder-query-import-new-files